# Snowflake - Connect Query History with Task?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, task

I'm trying to map Tasks to Query History for cost-allocation and dependency mapping.

There's a couple ways of doing this. I mean 'show tasks' will show the task definition -- you can map the query texts (or first 100 chars, or similarity, whatever).

Problem is, a task might be 'tweaked' slowly over time. Then the connection is lost.

Now, 'task history' maps a task to query id directly. However, it only has 7 days of data. Is this still the best option? Should I just have jobs that persist this history?

Or ... should I write tasks to input a query slug hash (in comment text) after each query? Trying to thing of the best long-term scalable way to do this.

Comment: I’d start with the TASK_HISTORY view