# Snowflake - How to preserve Task -> Query lineage over time?

Tags: dependencies, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, task

Snowflake saves a lot of data with account_usage.query_history and access_history.

Trouble is, preserving the connection between scheduled Tasks and queries. This might be useful because a daily task might end up costing a lot of money.

Right now, I can connect Tasks to Queries simply by comparing the Task definition to the query history "query text" -- or at least a close match if it's dynamic.

But what if the Task definition significantly changes? Then 3 months ago, a query running 10 times a day might not be able to be associated back to a Task.

I think the solution is "Task History" - which snowflake only saves for 7 days by default. This specifically has a Task ID and Query ID. Only trouble - it's only for 7 days. Is it worth persisting a lightweight version of this table for up to a year? ... Or am I missing this data / lineage existing in some other fashion?

... I suppose one could theoretically "lookup" queries that change Tasks, and use that as a slowly changing dimension table, but that is a bit convoluted and might end up being a bear to maintain.

Comment: The task_history view contains data for the last 365 days, just like all the other history views in the account_usage schema. You seem to be confusing the table function (which only has data for the last 7 days) with the view. I also told you this the last time you asked this question - not sure why you are just raising it again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Snowflake - Connect Query History with Task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77943535/snowflake-connect-query-history-with-task)

Comment: Forgot I asked that - must have missed the distinction there